# Convert matrix to ranked matrix Python

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, rank

Hello I want to rank the following matrix:

```
[[' ', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood\n']
         [0.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.4472135954999579, 0.2886751345948129, 0.6804138174397716]]
```

It has to become this matrix:

How can I do this?

```
[['brood\n', 0.6804138174397716]
['appeltaart', 0.6666666666666666]
['appelstruif', 0.447213594999579]
['amandelbeschuit', 02886751345948129]
[' ', 0.0]]
```

Comment: I would suggest using `print(list(*zip(my_list)))`.

Comment: Sorry, you wanted to have it sorted, so just extra sort for that: `print(sorted(list(zip(*my_list)), key=lambda d: d[1], reverse=True))`

Comment: Thanks mate, perfect fix!

Comment: Just a trivial question why does your function add them as (a, b) instead of [a,b]?

Comment: Because `zip` returns a tuples, not lists. It shouldn't be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [[' ', 'appeltaart', 'appelstruif', 'amandelbeschuit', 'brood\n'],
         [0.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.4472135954999579, 0.2886751345948129, 0.6804138174397716]]
new_matrix = sorted([[matrix[0][i], matrix[1][i]] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))], reverse=True)
print(new_matrix)
```

Comment: That does not rank them from highest to lowest